# Bates Distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution

Good evening everyone. I might need some help on something. Suppose we have $n$ independent variables from $U[0,1+θ]$ and suppose also that $λ=1+θ$. The estimator of $θ$ is $\bar{θ}=2 \bar{X} - 1$. Ι need to find the bias of $\bar{θ}$ knowing that the  distribution of $\bar{X}$ of $n$ variables, which they are from $U[0,1]$ , is the Bates distribution, which has the following probability density function: $$f(x)=\frac{n}{2(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(nx - k)^{(n-1)} sgn(nx -k)$$

where $\begin{cases}sgn(nx-k)&=&-1,\ & \text{if} \   \ nx<k\\ sgn(nx-k)&=& \ \  \ 0, & \text{if} \   \ nx=k\\  sgn(nx -k)&=& \ \  \ 1, &\text{if} \  \ nx > k \  \end{cases}$.

Comment: Latex: use "backslash" instead of "slash" and enclose your formulas by dollar signs.

Comment: What do you mean by "but from the U[0,1] distribution" ?

Comment: Thank you very much for editing. I posted it again here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546271/bates-and-uniform-distribution

Comment: You should not post it again ! I advise you to suppress the last one and improve this one.

Comment: I mean that $\bar{X}$ of $n$ variables from $U[0,1]$ has the following probability density function, but at the problem I have to solve the variables are from $U[0,1+θ]$.

Comment: The exponent is (n-1) not (k-1).

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb E[2 \bar{X} - 1\mid \theta] = 2 \,\mathbb E[\bar{X}\mid \theta] - 1 = 2 \left(\frac{1+\theta}{2}\right) - 1 = \theta$$

so $\bar{θ}=2 \bar{X} - 1$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$, and you do not need to consider the distribution of $\bar{X}$ beyond its expected value

Incidentally, a better unbiased estimator for $\theta$ might be $\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right) \max\limits_i(X_i)-1$